# how to use all my computer capacities

Tags: windows-7, performance

I see that my computer didn't exceed 20% of CPU and 60% of memery used, and sometimes it is slow.
my question is how can I force it to use all the necessary capacities in order to be fast .
Thank you in advance .

Comment: Install [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/); that will use 100% or your CPU.

Comment: you are not accounting for everything the PC does with those simple metrics. IO is the slowest activity, and accounts for most of the processing lag, and windows is responsible for scheduling what apps get how much access to thread execution facilities, so its not as though your computer could move faster; it does pretty much everything as fast as it possibly can.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't.

Applications draw the resources they require and for most applications that's that. Some applications throttle resource usage so as not to monopolize the resources and give you a setting to change the limit, but most don't. Either way, the amount of resources used is determined by the application, not the user (for the most part). Usually a computer is slow when it doesn't have enough of some resource for all the applications trying to use it.